# Application Process is getting killed when we change the date and time of the device

Tags: android, performance

We have an application in which we do following:
 - Launch Application , launch some activities in it. 
 - Press Home screen
 - Go to Settings , Change Date and time settings
 - Check DDMS , the process is killed and again restarted.

But as the new context is created , all other items depending upon it are not initialized and when we try to open the application again it gets crashed.
Is it possible to get an event if the application process is killed and launched again.

Help Appreciated.

Comment: it's not the process getting killed, it's `Activity` at the moment when you change Date and time settings. that current `Activity` is killed and control goes back to its parent

Comment: You should post your code and log cat!